# Faster way to retrieve a page and manipulate returned content than file_get_contents?

Tags: php, dom

I am having to retrieve some content from an external site, manipulate it and display it on another website. It is a table of financial data. However, it is pretty slow to load - > 3 sec. Before I have to shim it with a loading div, I would like to see if I could speed it up in any way, possibly leverage cURL? Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('https://exernalsite.com');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadhtml($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $rows = $xpath->query('//table')->item(2)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    foreach($rows as $index => $row) {
      $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
      if ($cells->length > 4 && $index < 6) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
     {        
      if ($i != 4) {
        echo "<td>" . $cells->item($i)->textContent . "</td>\n";
      }
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you put in microtimer echos to bench exactly what part of your code causes the most slowdown? If its just file_get_contents thats doing it... using curl most likely will not speed things up :( Also, if you've benchmarked just accessing the external site alone in a browser (maybe their site is just sllooow)?

Comment: Maybe, you also could store a cache data.

Comment: Yeah, a cache system could be a good idea, depending on how often the external site data changes, or how up to the second it needs to be utilized.

Comment: These are some futures margins that are only updated once a month